# Classification of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$-forms of an algebraic group

Tags: extension-field, algebraic-groups

The classification of forms of algebraic groups is generally only done for Galois extensions $L/K$. One gets a description of all $L/K$-forms of an algebraic $K$-group in terms of Galois cohomology.

But how do I find the algebraic $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$-groups of some fixed algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-group $\mathbf{G}$ ? I thought maybe it is enough to classify the $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}$-forms of $\mathbf{G}$, but then I would need something like this:

> Let $\mathbf{G}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ be linear algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-groups which are isomorphic as $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-groups. Then are they also isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}$-groups, or are at least $
> \mathbf{G}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbf{H}(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic as real Lie groups?

If there is no general answer, how does one proceed in the case $\mathbf{G} = \mathbf{SL_n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't ask the question you meant to ask. Of course it's not true that $G_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}} \cong H_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ implies $G_{\mathbb{R}} \cong H_{\mathbb{R}}$; a simple counterexample is $G = \mathbb{G}_m$, $H = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}: a^2 + b^2 = 1\right\}$ -- there is an isomorphism between the two of these over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ given by sending $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}$ to $a + i b$, but $G(\mathbb{R})$ and $H(\mathbb{R})$ are trivially not isomorphic as real Lie groups, because one is compact and the other is not.

What you probably meant to ask is the converse: if $G_{\mathbb{R}} \cong H_{\mathbb{R}}$, does this imply $G_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}} \cong H_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$? This is rather less obvious, but it is still true. Intuitively, the reason it holds is this: to find an isomorphism $G_K \cong H_K$ for some field $K$, you have to find solutions in $K$ to some finite collection of polynomial equations (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$); and if these have solutions over $\mathbb{R}$, they must have solutions over some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Very interesting. So do I get it right that it follows from what you wrote that every $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$-form of a given $\mathbb{Q}$-group $\mathbf{G}$ will appear in the list of all the $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}$-forms of $\mathbf{G}$ and thus in order to find all the $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$-forms of $\mathbf{G}$ it suffices to check which of the $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}$-forms of $\mathbf{G}$ are defined over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Is there any reference for this result? I don't quite understand the sketch of the proof. Thank you!